# How to end java program

Tags: java

Do I have to add some `exit` statement?

Code seems to be running well, but after it finish its task I still can't interact with console.

[image]

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package excelb;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


/**
 *
 * @author hp
 */
public class Excelb {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String row;
        String row2;
        File fn = null;
        int counter = 0;



        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the run identifier for output file");
        String output = in.nextLine();


        //input
        JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        jFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:/"));

        int result = jFileChooser.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());


        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
             fn=jFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println("Data file: " + fn.getAbsolutePath());
            //System.out.println("Data file: " + fn.getTitle());
        }



        BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Keywords.csv"));
        BufferedReader csvReader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fn.getAbsolutePath()));

        row = csvReader.readLine();
        String[] data = row.split(",");
        while (counter < data.length) {
            while ((row2 = csvReader2.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] data2 = row2.split(",");
                for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                    if ((data2[data2.length - 1].contains(data[j]))) {
                        //DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
                        //Date dateobj = new Date();
                        //String d = df.format(dateobj);
                        //d = d.replaceAll("/", "");
                        String newFile = data[j] + "_" + output + ".csv";
                        FileWriter csvWriter = new FileWriter(newFile, true);
                        for (int i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
                           csvWriter.append(data2[i]);
                            csvWriter.append(",");
                        }
                        csvWriter.append("\n");
                        csvWriter.close();
                    }
                }
            }
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.println("Finished");
        csvReader.close();
        csvReader2.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to use a loop to iterate the processing logic

Comment: You know, now would be a great time to start using Windows new and improved subsystem for Linux.  CMD is the most developed unfriendly command line I know of

Answer (score 3):

Pshemo's answer explains why your app isn't ending.

But it does fail to make the key point, which is:

To exit a Java app, run `System.exit(0);` - and consider returning a non-0 value if errors occurred. Don't wait for the JVM to exit itself (it does do so, once the only remaining live threads have the daemon flag set) - that's a frail strategy if the point is to close the app. Just call `exit`.

Comment: Edited my answer to include missing portion. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: i put this in and it wouldnt compile

Comment: c:\java>javac Excelb.java
Excelb.java:102: error: <identifier> expected
System.exit(0);
           ^
Excelb.java:102: error: illegal start of type
System.exit(0);
            ^
2 errors

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem:

Your application consists of two separate threads:

1. handling `main` method
2. handling events from *swing* events.

Even if *main* thread will end its execution, *swing* thread is still running and doesn't allow your application to exit.
BTW that is a good thing. We are building GUI components like frames with buttons, labels, etc. in `main` method. Now, when main method/thread ends, should application be closed and along with it all built GUI? That wouldn't make much sense.

#### Why problem appeared?

Because you used `new JFrame()` which started swing thread responsible for handling events related to swing/AWT components (like button clicks, etc.).

### Solutions:

#### Approach 1: Prevent problem from happening

Don't start swing thread with `new JFrame()` if you are not planning to create application based on swing GUI.

In your case simple solution would be passing `null` instead of `new JFrame()` to `jFileChooser.showOpenDialog`. This would also let that dialog be placed at the center of the screen:

```
int result = jFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

#### Approach 2: Forceful exit

To forcefully close your application you can use `System.exit(0)`.

*But generally it is better to **prevent** problems from happening than solving them.*

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1F6pODH3lffpmSMRxWQTFb-bJ44RqAQUp

Comment: c:\java>javac Excelb.java
Excelb.java:102: error: <identifier> expected
System.exit(0);
           ^
Excelb.java:102: error: illegal start of type
System.exit(0);
            ^
2 errors

Comment: Where exactly did you put `System.exit(0);` in your code? It should be placed at the end of `main` method (since at this point we want to exit). Anyway have you tried using `null` instead of `new JFrame()`? IMO it is preferred solution over `System.exit(0);` since it *prevents* problem forom happening, instead of solving problem created by `new JFrame()`.